# Launching the SPA proxy

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc

I want to run a web application, developed in NET Core with React.

Everything compiles fine, but when I want to start the application it gives me the following errors
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jRind.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2i6yp.jpg)

I already installed the necessary packages, but maybe I'm still missing something. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

seems your project isn't launching the spaproxy or it can't run either, i was in a similar situation with quick solving due it was another scenario.

your project is divided in two sections, the aspnet website itself, and the react app, both residing inside the same project.

you can still use areas and views in the aspnet website but, when you try to navigate home, spaproxy middleware is redirecting you to the proxy application, wich isn't running, try to start, but npm run doesn't work and you can't see react.

your react app resides inside ClientApp/ directory and is in that directory where the packages must reside, so if you moved, renamed, or some other tamperig, without reclect these changes in the project file, the whole thing won't work. AND node_packages MUST be inside that directory, not in the website  project root... They are two separate applications and npm packages residing in one are not shared with the other.

Comment: Try to share your problem and piece of code here to really help you out. This is not a way to ask. Kindly read the instructions of how to ask question in StackOverFlow.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34842645)